# Finding a set of packs to merge to equal a given pack

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

`typename FindPacksToMerge<P<Packs...>, P<Ts...>>::type` is `P<As...>` such that `As...` is a sequence of packs from `Packs...` (possibly with repeats) and

```
std::is_same< typename concat<As...>::type, P<Ts...> >::value == true
```

For example,

```
std::cout << std::is_same<
    FindPacksToMerge< P< P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int> >, P<int, bool, char, int, int, double, bool> >::type,
    P< P<int>, P<bool, char, int>, P<int>, P<double, bool> >
>::value << '\n';
```

should output true.  For now let's be content with getting any answer, in case there are multiple answers.

I've written the relevant helper structs already (`concat` merges any number of packs, `split<N, Pack>` splits a pack so that the head with N types and the tail can be obtained, `pack_size` gives the number of types in the pack):

```
template <typename T> struct Identity { using type = T; };

template <typename...> struct concat;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat<P<Ts...>, P<Us...>> {
    using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <typename Pack>
struct concat<Pack> : Identity<Pack> {};

template <typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct concat<Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> {
    using type = typename concat<Pack1, typename concat<Pack2, Packs...>::type>::type;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Intput, typename... Output> struct split;

template <std::size_t N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<N, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> : split<N-1, P<Rest...>, Output..., First> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<First, Rest...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<>;
};

template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> {};
```

But the problem is the recursion.  Let's say among the types in `P<Packs...>`, we are testing out type `Pack`.  If `split<pack_size<Pack>::value, P<Ts...>>::head` matches `Pack`, then repeat the search with `split<pack_size<Pack>::value, P<Ts...>>::tail` (starting the search in `P<Packs...>` back at its first pack).  We store all the found packs in an output pack along the way.  When we reach near the end of `P<Ts...>` and find that the remaining tail is shorter or equal in length to the shortest pack in `P<Packs...>`, and does not match any pack in `P<Packs...>`, then the search along this line has failed.  Thus we have to start the search again.  But from where?  From the last pack that was tried (we must now try the pack after that).  And if all the packs after that also fails to give an answer, then we must go back one step again, but where is that?  This is a tree-traversal, but how to remember were we left off at any number of generations up?  Or maybe there is a better approach altogether?  Trying to merge all possible combinations from `P<Packs...>` until it matches `P<Ts...>` cannot possibly be a viable solution.

This is the template specialization I'm currently working on, which needs to be fixed.  I have a feeling the fix that eludes me is a short one.

```
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match> struct FindPacksToMergeHelper;

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> : std::conditional_t<
    pack_size<Match>::value < pack_size<First>::value,
    FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match>,  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.
    std::conditional_t<
        std::is_same<First, Match>::value,
        Identity<P<Output..., First>>,  // Answer found.
        std::conditional_t<
            std::is_same<First, typename split<pack_size<First>::value, Match>::head>::value,  // Check if the head of Match is the same as First.
            FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks, P<Output..., First>, typename split<pack_size<First>::value, Match>::tail>,  // Try with the tail now, starting back at the first type in PackOfPacks.
            FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match>  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.
        >
    >
> {};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pack:

```
template<class... > class pack {};
```

Filter a pack of types by a predicate:

```
template<class, class Pred> struct filter;

template<class... Ts, class F>
struct filter<pack<Ts...>, F>
{
    using type = typename concat<std::conditional_t<F::template apply<Ts>::value,
                                                    pack<Ts>,
                                                    pack<>>...>::type;
};
```

A predicate for "is U a prefix of T":

```
template<class T>
struct is_prefix_of
{
    template<class U, bool = pack_size<T>::value >= pack_size<U>::value>
    struct apply;
    template<class U>
    struct apply<U, true> 
        : std::is_same<U, typename split<pack_size<U>::value, T>::head> { };
    template<class U>
    struct apply<U, false> : std::false_type {};
};
```

Tag type to indicate failure:

```
struct fail;
```

The beast:

```
template<class Packs, class Pack,
         class Current = typename filter<Packs, is_prefix_of<Pack>>::type> 
struct find_packs_to_merge;

template<class Packs, class Pack, class First, class... Rest>
struct find_packs_to_merge<Packs, Pack, pack<First, Rest...>>
{
    // Get the remainder of the pack we still need to work on
    using Remaining = typename split<pack_size<First>::value, Pack>::tail;
    // search for the packs needed for the tail
    using PR = typename find_packs_to_merge<Packs, Remaining>::type;

    // on failure, try the next pack 
    // on success, concat First to PR and we are done.
    // Note the short circuiting.
    using type = typename std::conditional_t<std::is_same<fail, PR>::value, 
                                    find_packs_to_merge<Packs, Pack, pack<Rest...>>,
                                    concat<pack<First>, PR>>::type;
};

template<class Packs, class Pack>
struct find_packs_to_merge<Packs, Pack, pack<>>
{
    // we tried everything and nothing works.
    using type = fail;
};

template<class Packs>
struct find_packs_to_merge<Packs, pack<>, pack<>>
{
   // Success - we've used up the pack.
    using type = pack<>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not read T.C.'s solution yet, as I persisted with my method.  The following code passes for 6 test cases, but I don't know if it works for any possible case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct Identity { using type = T; };

template <typename...> struct concat;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat<P<Ts...>, P<Us...>> {
    using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <typename Pack>
struct concat<Pack> : Identity<Pack> {};

template <typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct concat<Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> {
    using type = typename concat<Pack1, typename concat<Pack2, Packs...>::type>::type;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Intput, typename... Output> struct split;

template <std::size_t N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<N, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> : split<N-1, P<Rest...>, Output..., First> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<First, Rest...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<>;
};

template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> {};

struct Failed;

template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match> struct FindPacksToMergeImpl;
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, typename Result> struct Check;
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match> struct FindPacksToMergeHelper;
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckIfPackTooBig;
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckIfAnswerFound;
template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckHead;

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfPackTooBig<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfPackTooBig<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    CheckIfAnswerFound<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, std::is_same<First, Match>::value> {};

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfAnswerFound<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> : Identity<P<Output..., First>> {};  // We are done.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfAnswerFound<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    CheckHead<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, std::is_same<First, typename split<pack_size<First>::value, Match>::head>::value> {};  // Check if the head of Match is the same as First.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckHead<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks, P<Output..., First>, typename split<pack_size<First>::value, Match>::tail> {};  // Try with the tail now, starting back at the first type in PackOfPacks.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckHead<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> :
    CheckIfPackTooBig<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, pack_size<Match>::value < pack_size<First>::value> {};

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<>, P<Output...>, Match> : Identity<Failed> {};

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match, typename Result>
struct Check<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, Result> : Identity<Result> {};  // We are done.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct Check<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, Failed> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> :
    Check<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, typename FindPacksToMergeHelper<PackOfPacks, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match>::type> {};

template <typename PackOfPacks, template <typename...> class P, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, P<>, P<Output...>, Match> : Identity<Failed> {};  // This should never be reached, but is needed to compile (it was really hard to check why though).

template <typename> struct EmptyPack;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct EmptyPack<P<Ts...>> { using type = P<>; };

template <typename PackOfPacks, typename Match>
using FindPacksToMerge = typename FindPacksToMergeImpl<PackOfPacks, PackOfPacks, typename EmptyPack<PackOfPacks>::type, Match>::type;

// Testing
template <typename...> struct P;

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P<P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int>>, P<bool, char, int> >,
        P< P<bool, char, int> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P<P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int>>, P<bool, char, int, bool, char, int> >,
        P< P<bool, char, int>, P<bool, char, int> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P<P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int>>, P<bool, char, int, double, bool> >,
        P< P<bool, char, int>, P<double, bool> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P< P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int> >, P<int, bool, char, int, int, double, bool> >,
        P< P<int>, P<bool, char, int>, P<int>, P<double, bool> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P< P<int, bool>, P<int, char, long>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int> >, P<int, bool, char, int, int, double, bool> >,
        P< P<int>, P<bool, char, int>, P<int>, P<double, bool> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true (this works even though P<int, bool> is tried (and fails) before P<int> is tried)

    std::cout << std::is_same<
        FindPacksToMerge< P< P<int, bool>, P<int, char, long>, P<bool>, P<int>, P<double, bool>, P<bool, char, int> >, P<int, bool, char, int, int, double, bool> >,
        P< P<int>, P<bool, char, int>, P<int>, P<double, bool> >
    >::value << '\n';  // true (this works even though after P<int> is correctly tried (after P<int, bool> is tried and failed), then P<bool> is tried (and fails) before P<bool, char, int> is tried)
}
```

I will work on T.C.'s ideas now.

For those who are wondering, here is an application of `FindTypesToMerge` that motivated this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T> struct Identity { using type = T; };

template <typename...> struct concat;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
struct concat<P<Ts...>, P<Us...>> {
    using type = P<Ts..., Us...>;
};

template <typename Pack>
struct concat<Pack> : Identity<Pack> {};

template <typename Pack1, typename Pack2, typename... Packs>
struct concat<Pack1, Pack2, Packs...> {
    using type = typename concat<Pack1, typename concat<Pack2, Packs...>::type>::type;
};

template <std::size_t N, typename Intput, typename... Output> struct split;

template <std::size_t N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<N, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> : split<N-1, P<Rest...>, Output..., First> {};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<First, Rest...>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<First, Rest...>;
};

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Output>
struct split<0, P<>, Output...> {
    using head = P<Output...>;
    using tail = P<>;
};

template <typename Pack> struct pack_size;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct pack_size<P<Ts...>> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, sizeof...(Ts)> {};

struct Failed;

template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match> struct FindPacksToMergeImpl;
template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, typename Result> struct Check;
template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match> struct FindPacksToMergeHelper;
template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckIfPackTooBig;
template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckIfAnswerFound;
template <typename Pack, typename Untried, typename Output, typename Match, bool> struct CheckHead;

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfPackTooBig<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfPackTooBig<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    CheckIfAnswerFound<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, std::is_same<typename First::argument_type, Match>::value> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfAnswerFound<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> : Identity<P<Output..., First>> {};  // We are done.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckIfAnswerFound<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    CheckHead<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, std::is_same<typename First::argument_type, typename split<pack_size<typename First::argument_type>::value, Match>::head>::value> {};  // Check if the head of Match is the same as First::argument_type.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckHead<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, true> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, Pack, P<Output..., First>, typename split<pack_size<typename First::argument_type>::value, Match>::tail> {};  // Try with the tail now, starting back at the first type in Pack.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct CheckHead<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, false> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeHelper<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> :
    CheckIfPackTooBig<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, pack_size<Match>::value < pack_size<typename First::argument_type>::value> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeHelper<Pack, P<>, P<Output...>, Match> : Identity<Failed> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match, typename Result>
struct Check<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, Result> : Identity<Result> {};  // We are done.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct Check<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, Failed> :
    FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, P<Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> {};  // Move on to the next of the untried packs.

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match> :
    Check<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match, typename FindPacksToMergeHelper<Pack, P<First, Rest...>, P<Output...>, Match>::type> {};

template <typename Pack, template <typename...> class P, typename... Output, typename Match>
struct FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, P<>, P<Output...>, Match> : Identity<Failed> {};  // This should never be reached, but is needed to compile (it was really hard to check why though).

template <typename> struct EmptyPack;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Ts>
struct EmptyPack<P<Ts...>> { using type = P<>; };

template <typename Pack, typename Match>
using FindPacksToMerge = typename FindPacksToMergeImpl<Pack, Pack, typename EmptyPack<Pack>::type, Match>::type;

template <typename... Ts>
class Storage {
    std::tuple<std::vector<Ts*>...> inventory;
    template <typename> struct AddDifferentTypes;
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    void addDifferentTypes (Args&&... args) {
        using TypesTuple = FindPacksToMerge<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Args...>>;  // FindPacksToMerge adapted from the FindPacksToMerge.cpp program.
        AddDifferentTypes<TypesTuple>::execute(this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    template <typename T>
    const std::vector<T*>& get() const {return std::get<std::vector<T*>>(inventory);}
private:
    template <typename T, typename... Args>
    void addItem (Args&&... args) {
        std::get<std::vector<T*>>(inventory).emplace_back(new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...});
    }
};

template <typename... Ts>
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Vs>
struct Storage<Ts...>::AddDifferentTypes<P<Vs...>> {
    template <typename... Args>
    static void execute (Storage<Ts...>* storage, Args&&... args) {
        executeHelper<0, 0, P<Vs...>, std::tuple_size<typename Vs::argument_type>::value...>(storage, std::tie(args...));
    }
private:
    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Offset, typename TypesTuple, std::size_t First, std::size_t... Rest, typename ArgsTuple>
    static void executeHelper (Storage<Ts...>* storage, const ArgsTuple& tuple) {
        add<N, Offset, TypesTuple>(storage, tuple, std::make_index_sequence<First>{});
        executeHelper<N + 1, Offset + First, TypesTuple, Rest...>(storage, tuple);
    }

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Offset, typename TypesTuple, typename ArgsTuple>
    static void executeHelper (Storage<Ts...>*, const ArgsTuple&) {}  // End of recursion. 

    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Offset, typename TypesTuple, typename ArgsTuple, std::size_t... Is>
    static void add (Storage<Ts...>* storage, const ArgsTuple& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
        storage->template addItem<std::tuple_element_t<N, TypesTuple>>(std::get<Offset + Is>(tuple)...);
    }
};

// Testing
struct Object {
    int a;
    bool b;
    char c;
    double d;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<int, bool, char, double>;
};

struct Thing {
    int a, b;
    char c;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<int, int, char>;
};

struct Number {
    int num;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<int>;
};

struct SemiObject {
    int a;
    bool b;
    char c;
    using argument_type = std::tuple<int, bool, char>;
};

int main() {
    Storage<Number, SemiObject, Object, Thing> storage;
    storage.addDifferentTypes (1,true,'a',3.5,   1,2,'t',   5,6,'p',  3,false,'b',1.8,   3,true,'t',  8,  3,  4,5,'s');  // Object, Thing, Thing, Object, SemiObject, Number, Number, Thing

    std::cout << "Objects: " << storage.get<Object>().size() << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << "Things: " << storage.get<Thing>().size() << '\n';  // 3
    std::cout << "Numbers: " << storage.get<Number>().size() << '\n';  // 2
    std::cout << "SemiObjects: " << storage.get<SemiObject>().size() << '\n';  // 1
}
```